# Pandas: From SettingWithCopyWarning to loc and iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to do:

```
input1['Signature_Fixed'] = 'NONE' 
i = 0

for row in input1['Signature']:
  if (row == 'Competitor'):
    input1['Signature_Fixed'][i] = input1['brand'][i]
  else:
    input1['Signature_Fixed'][i] = input1['Signature'][i]
  i = i + 1
```

When I am doing on 1K rows, it works but I have `SettingWithCopyWarning` then when I am doing on 2M rows, is not working.

Could you please help me to fix that and maybe to convert it with `loc`/`iloc`?

Comment: Did this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Do you want to set brand value where the row is `competitor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input1['Signature_Fixed'][i]` represents chained indexing, which is [explicitly discouraged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) in the official documentation. Avoid it wherever possible.

In this case, you can avoid `for` loops altogether by using [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
bool_mask = df['Signature'] == 'Competitor'
df['Signature_Fixed'] = df['Signature'].mask(bool_mask, df['brand'])
```

The idea in syntax terms is to operate on columns in *vectorised* fashion rather than on row-wise loops.